# What is a "tagged DFA"?

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures

I came across a regular expression library http://laurikari.net/tre/ and also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa , but I could not find anything about this "tagged DFA" approach that they are using: neither on the pages of these libraries, nor in google (incl.scholar).

Anyone know what it is about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a paper:

[NFAs with Tagged Transitions, their Conversion to Deterministic Automata and Application to Regular Expressions (2000) [PDF]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.4395&rep=rep1&type=pdf), written by Ville Laurikari.

Comment: Thanks! Incidentally, I've just found the same paper and also the actual thesis: <a href="http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.76.2799">Efficient Submatch Addressing for Regular Expressions</a>

Comment: @jkff: IIRC, Ville Laurikari had in his previous site a link to his  thesis pdf, but now he doesn't.

Comment: Alternative link to probably the same paper since citeseer didn't work for me https://laurikari.net/ville/spire2000-tnfa.pdf